# Export button greyed out in the archiver

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to create an ad-hoc distribution for my IOS app. When I go: XCODE > Menu > Product > Archive, this completes successfully but the 'Export' button is disabled with the message below: "Distribution Required Enrollment in the Apple Developer Program".

I must have missed out a step in registering or some setting. Can enyone help figure out what I've done wrong. This is what I have...

I joined the Apple Developer Program. And in the Apple Member Centre:

- Account Type: Company/Organisation
- MyName is listed with role: agent

Under Certificates (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate)..

- MyCompanyName: iOS Distribution
- MyName: iOS Development

Under Identifiers > APP IDs...

- Xcode IOS wildcard app id: *

Under Devices...

- My iPad is listed

Under Provisioning Profiles...

- MyNameProfile1, iOS Distribution, Active
- iOS Team Provisioning Profile:*, iOS Development, Active (Managed by XCODE)

Within XCode...

Menu > xcode > Prefs > Apple ID > my apple developer id is listed, and it contains..

- TeamName = MyName (personal team), iOS = Free, MAC = Free
- TeamName = MyCompanyName, iOS = Agent, MAC = Agent

In xcode, when I have the .xcodeproje file selected, in the middle window, I have...

- Team: MyName (Personal team)

And when I press the 'run' button with my iPad selected, the app builds and launches on my iPad without problems. However if I select: Team MyCompany name, and try to build, I get "App installation failed. The app could not be verified". (So I dont use this account).

I must admit I dont understand why MyName and MyCompany name are listed and what the difference is. And I dont understand what xcode is creating and if I maybe have to download some certificate or something for xcode to use.

Also I used cordova to create the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't export under your personal team.  You need to use the company account and fix your 'installation failed' issue.

Try deleting the app off the device you're trying to run it on.  If it was installed under a different provisioning profile, such as your personal team one, then Xcode may not be able to overwrite the current version of your already installed app with the new one with the new profile from your company.  So delete it and try running again.

Comment: Thank you very much - that fixed it. I uninstalled the app, and then in xcode selected the company for 'team' (rather than my-name) and it build fine and I was then also able to generate an archive.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility for some:

> If you don’t belong to the Apple Developer Program, a personal team appears.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingYourAccounttoXcode/AddingYourAccounttoXcode.html

Basically go and register for the Apple Developer Program here:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/

Answer (score 0):

I just changed "Development Team" of project and target from "My Name (Personal Team)" to "My Name" and Export button enabled!

Comment: can you explain a bit more.. Im not in the Apple Developer Program, but I want to produce a debug ipa for testing, can you help! thanx

Comment: When your account isn't paid (or free), it behaves like a personal team. Personal teams can't export your archive. That is the part that makes the .IPA file available to you. (just went thru that this year, had to be confused by the error, then pay, then it worked.)